# Read data from Json and populate Span tags

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have the following form using AlpineJS:

```
<form x-data="inquiry()" x-on:submit.prevent="submit" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" x-model="data.email">
  <span name="email-validator" display="none"></span>

  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="my subject" x-model="data.subject">
  <span name="subject-validator" display="none"></span>

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I submit the form with errors I get the Json object:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "email": "The email is required",
    "subject": "The subject is invalid"
  }
}
```

I need, for each error, to make its validator `span` visible and add the validation message.

And the submission javascript code is:

```
<script>
  function inquiry() {
    return {
      data: {
        email: "",
        subject: ""
      },
      submit() {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));

        fetch("/inquiries", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(this.data),
        })
          .then(() => {
            this.data.email = "";
          })
          .catch(() => {
            // POPULATE Errors into SPANS here
          });

      }
    };
  }
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object for the validator text as well, so Alpine.js can show them dynamically with e.g. `x-show="error_msg.email"`:

```
<form x-data="inquiry()" x-on:submit.prevent="submit" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" x-model="data.email">
  <span name="email-validator" x-text="error_msg.email" x-show="error_msg.email"></span>

  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="my subject" x-model="data.subject">
  <span name="subject-validator" x-text="error_msg.subject" x-show="error_msg.subject"></span>

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And at the `catch` branch, we loop over the `error_msg` object and set the error message from the response object.

```
function inquiry() {
  return {
    data: {
      email: "",
      subject: ""
    },
    error_msg: {
      email: "",
      subject: ""
    },
    submit() {
      fetch("/inquiries", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.data),
      })
        .then(() => {
          this.data.email = "";
        })
        .catch((response) => {
          Object.entries(this.error_msg).forEach(([key, val]) => {
            this.error_msg[key] = response.error[key]
          })
        });
    }
  };
}
```